# Scrape page and send user only new results

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

### Review Wanted

#### Application Summary

The application is a simple screen scraper which is to notify the user when new items are posted.

The code is run as a CRON job every ten minutes. It will scrape the target page and return an array of ALL items matching the search criteria ( hard-coded ) by the user.

The results are compared to the results from the previous time the code was run. If there are any new items, the user is notified.

#### My Challenges

First of all, I have never used any of the technologies I had to use in the app ( NodeJS, Puppeteer, and Express ). More significant that is, how to track what constitutes a "new" item, an item that has been "seen", etc.

Currently, I added a column in the database, "seen". When the user hits the front end, I will mark those results as "seen".

Also, the way I am saving the items in general may need refactoring. I will leave that up to your opinion.

#### WorkFlow

Here is a breakdown of how the app works:

[image: WorkFlow]

#### Source Code

Here is the complete source code of the app. It functions well, as far as I can tell. I am concerned about the Duplicate issue though.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const _ = require("lodash");
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mydatabase'
});

var oldItems; // Items already scraped


getSavedJeeps = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        con.query(
            "SELECT * FROM jeeps",
            function (err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(new Error("Error rows is undefined"));
                } else {
                    resolve(rows);
                }
            }
        )
    })
}

const saveNewJeeps = async function (entity) {

    let objLen = entity.length;

    // FOR EACH OBJECT IN ARRAY...
    for (var i = 0; i < objLen; i++) {
        var savedJeeps = con.query('INSERT INTO newjeeps SET ?', entity[i], function (err, result) {
            // Neat!
            console.log("Save function complete");
        });
    }

    removeDupes();
    return true;

}

const updateAllItems = async function (entity) {

    let objLen = entity.length;

    // FOR EACH OBJECT IN ARRAY...
    for (var i = 0; i < objLen; i++) {
        var savedJeeps = con.query('INSERT INTO jeeps SET ?', entity[i], function (err, result) {
            // Neat!
            console.log("Save function complete");
        });
    }


}

// Gets current items  Search Results
const getItems = async searchTerm => {

    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        timeout: 0,
        args: ["--no-sandbox"]
    });

    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`https://facebook.com/marketplace/tampa/search/?query=${encodeURI(searchTerm)}&sort=created_date_descending&exact=false`);
    await autoScroll(page);

    const itemList = await page.waitForSelector('div > div > span > div > a[tabindex="0"]')
        .then(() => page.evaluate(() => {

            const itemArray = [];
            const itemNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('div > div > span > div > a[tabindex="0"]');

            itemNodeList.forEach(item => {

                const itemTitle = item.innerText;
                const itemURL = item.getAttribute('href');
                const itemImg = item.querySelector('div > div > span > div > a > div > div > div > div > div > div > img').getAttribute('src');

                var obj = ['price', 'title', 'location', 'miles',
                        ...itemTitle.split(/\n/)
                    ]
                    .reduce((a, c, i, t) => {
                        if (i < 4) a[c] = t[i + 4]
                        return a
                    }, {});

                obj.imgUrl = itemImg;
                obj.itemURL = itemURL;

                itemArray.push(obj);
            });

            return itemArray;

        }))
        .catch(() => console.log("Selector error."));

    return itemList;

}


// This takes care of the auto scrolling problem
async function autoScroll(page) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 100;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight || scrollHeight > 9000) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    });
}

const removeDupes = async function () {
    // remove duplicates
    sql = `DELETE
    t1
FROM
    jeeps t1
INNER JOIN jeeps t2 WHERE
    t1.title < t2.title AND t1.price = t2.price `;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        con.query(
            sql,
            function (err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(new Error("Error rows is undefined"));
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            }
        )
    })
}

const getDifferences = async function (objNew, objOld) {
    console.log("Inside Differences")
    return _.difference(objNew, objOld);
}

const init = async function () {
    var oldItems;
    const newItems = await getItems("Jeep Wrangler");

    getSavedJeeps()
        .then(function (results) {
            oldItems = results;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Promise rejection error: " + err);
        })


    const finalArray = await getDifferences(newItems, oldItems);
    const saveSuccess = await saveNewJeeps(finalArray);
    const saveSuccess2 = await updateAllItems(finalArray);
    const changed = (finalArray.length > 0) ? true : false;
    
    if (changed) {
        // Fire Off Email
        const page2 = await browser.newPage();
        await page2.goto(`http://john.example.com/mail.php`);
    }

}


init();
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions or comments. I asked a similar question a while back, but the app wasn't ready for review. It is now, and I am ready for your review - whether good or bad.

Regards,
John

Comment: Your `init` function is not waiting for the `getSavedJeeps` function to finish before calling `getDifferences`; `oldItems` will always be `undefined`, so `getDifferences` will always return the `newItems` unaltered. There are also a whole bunch of improvements described in the prior answer on the code in the question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242044 that don't appear to have been implemented. (not that you have to implement them all, but many of them are concrete improvements without disadvantages or database restructuring)

Comment: I just don't understand why it isn't waiting. What more can I do? It's already async. As far as the other improvements, I appreciated the suggestions, but I wanted to try to get it working before I refactor. I think I bit off more than I could chew for a first project. Ok, I will dig in and see why getSavedJeeps is not waiting. Thank you so much CP.

Comment: The issue is similar to the one described in great detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086). In short, you should `await` the Promise in order for the current function to stop execution until the Promise resolves.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, but I have a question for you.

## Question

Why don't you use the jeep id of Facebook as a unique key, this way duplicates will not be a problem.

## Now for the code review

Notes:

- I saw other responses told you you have bugs in your code, I didn't check your code for bugs. But please follow their advice.
- This is my add-on above all that was already been told by others.

---

1. The first impression the code looks good for its purpose.
   What I mean - the code is a small CRON script and therefore using a **single file** might be ok for the use-case. Although code tends to grow or even infrastructure might change.
2. The code is broken into meaningful functions and is easy to read. and it's ok because its a small CRON job otherwise another structure was required.

   - For example the non-readable parts are some of the boilerplate code that is scattered around which is the misfortune of a single file.
   - Another example of such misfortune is not needing to be object-oriented and have a clear responsibility structure embedded which makes the code less readable.
   - Yet another - There is no sense of layers in your code, so it's just simple progressive programming. If it was part of a bigger project, I would expect it to use existing DB layers or other existing infrastructure and may be part of a single monorepo and layers would have been a must and different restructuring.
3. Good use of promise & await, but why not stick with one method? promisify the endpoints and keep the consistency of async/await from there on to the top level.
4. very important, I read another person told you the same thing, you didn't handle catch-all exception in one location.